# asctime/localtime output error

Tags: c, datetime

```
char timestamp()
{
    time_t ltime;
    struct tm * loctime;
    char thetime;
    time(&ltime);
    loctime=localtime(&ltime);
    printf("%s", asctime(loctime));
    // "Sat Mar  2 12:12:57 2013"
    thetime=*asctime(loctime);
    // why "83"?!
    return thetime;
}

void WriteLog(char* Msg, ...)
{
    FILE logfile;
    logfile=*fopen(LOG_FILE, "r+");
    fseek(&logfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(&logfile, "%hhd, %s", timestamp(), Msg);
    fclose(&logfile);
}
```

I have a feeling there's a very basic mistake here. When I print time, it's perfectly fine, but when I try assigning it to variable to be used in another function, I get `83` instead of the actual date and time, and when I remove asterisk from `asctime(loctime)`, I get `-128` and a warning from the compiler: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is just a single ASCII character whereas `char*` is a pointer to a memory location usually used to hold a character array i.e. a string.

The value was `83` which corresponded to ASCII character `S` which came from the first character of your timestamp string `Sat Mar  2 12:12:57 2013`

Instead try this code which returns the `char*` directly that could be used for writing to the log file.

```
char* timestamp()
{
    time_t ltime;
    struct tm * loctime;
    char thetime;
    time(&ltime);
    loctime=localtime(&ltime);
    printf("%s", asctime(loctime));
    // "Sat Mar  2 12:12:57 2013"
    return asctime(loctime);
}

void WriteLog(char* Msg, ...)
{
    FILE logfile;
    logfile=*fopen(LOG_FILE, "r+");
    fseek(&logfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(&logfile, "%hhd, %s", timestamp(), Msg);
    fclose(&logfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is just a single character, not a string. To declare a variable pointing to a string, you must use `char *`.

So it should be:

```
char *thetime;
```

Then the assignment should be:

```
thetime = asctime(loctime);
```

The declaration of `timestamp` should be:

```
char *timestamp()
```

And when you print the time in `WriteLog`, it should be:

```
fprintf(&logfile, "%s, %s", timestamp(), Msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared both the timestamp function and thetime variable as `char`. This is a 1-byte variable which can hold only an integer in the range -128 to +127. What you want is a pointer (`char *`) instead so that they can hold and return the pointer to the string returned by asctime.

Change both declarations from `char` to `char *` and remove the `*` that deferences the return from asctime. That should fix it.